# prove that $f(\theta)=\max _{V^{T} V=I} \operatorname{Tr}\left[V^{T}(A-\theta B) V\right]$ is a decreasing function of $\theta$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Assuming that $A$ is symmetric , $V$ an arbitary unitary matrix and $B$ positive definite. How I can prove that $f(\theta)=\max _{V^{T} V=I} \operatorname{Tr}\left[V^{T}(A-\theta B) V\right]$ is a decreasing function of $\theta$ and for $\theta=0$ we have $f(\theta)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It suffices to note that $g_V(\theta) = \operatorname{Tr}[V^T(A - \theta B)V]$ is a decreasing function for all orthogonal matrices $V$.

Comment: How can I prove it. May I need to calculate the derivative?

Comment: You do not need to calculate a derivative. Just use the linearity of the trace function to write $g$ in the form $g(\theta) = \alpha \theta + \beta$ for scalars $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: I don't see how to conclude that the function is decreasing by using the linearity of the trace function? can you please explain more

Comment: The function $g(\theta) = \alpha \theta + \beta$ is decreasing whenever $\alpha$ is negative.